# when `npm login` with correct account and password , why still get 'Incorrect username or password'?

Tags: npm

I cannot use my pair of username and password to run `npm login` success in terminal, while

I use a pair of account and password to login npmjs.com website. But when execute `npm login` in terminal, this error appeared:

```
npm WARN adduser Incorrect username or password
npm WARN adduser You can reset your account by visiting:
npm WARN adduser
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

View npm config through `npm config ls`, check the registry

```
→ npm config ls
; cli configs
user-agent = "npm/2.14.2 node/v4.0.0 darwin x64"

; userconfig /Users/xxx/.npmrc
email = "xxx@xx.com"
registry = "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/"
```

If you use third party registry like 'taobao.org' etc., you will absolutely get the 'Incorrect username or password' error tip.

### Solution

Change back to use official registry `npmjs.org` temporarily:

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: Also make sure that you are not mistakenly passing a `--registry` argument to the command line. I had this error trying to log into NPM but using `--registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`.