# Npm login doesn't work - multiple password prompts repeating

Tags: npm

When I do npm login and copy paste my password into the password prompt the password prompt just appears again. I verified that copying and pasting into the terminal works correctly so I'm not sure what's happening. I verified that my password is correct. I already read through [npm ERR! code E401 npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114659/npm-err-code-e401-npm-err-incorrect-or-missing-password) and [when `npm login` with correct account and password , why still get 'Incorrect username or password'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207905/when-npm-login-with-correct-account-and-password-why-still-get-incorrect-us) but neither seemed relevant.

NPM: v7.5.4

NODE: 14.15.1

OS: Windows

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very simple - I had to manually type in my password instead of copying and pasting it. This is odd given that copying and pasting in the command prompt works normally. I guess either Windows command prompt has a weird quirk where pasting into password prompts doesn't work or it's some npm-specific bug, not sure.